# Is Jesus saying "God willing" the same as "Insallah", said by Muslims before doing anything?

Tags: words-of-jesus

Is Jesus saying "God willing" the same as "Insallah" said by Muslims before doing anything?

Comment: For whomever VtC: An answer to this is not necessarily opinion based if it can be shown that an analysis of Semitic languages and/or the various carry overs from Judaism and Christianity (people of the Book, according to the Prophet) show them both being from a similar cultural or belief-based root.  Richard, you may wish to add a little meat to this question.  On what basis to you feel that the similarity is germane to Christian belief?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: That would make it off-topic, though. (Although possibly on topic at Linguistics)

Comment: An on-topic (but still opinion based) question here would be "What did Jesus mean when he said 'God willing'?" Perhaps a question along those lines would fit on BH, if it references a specific verse.  And a similar one on Islam for "Insallah". The answers to those two questions might be what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Flimzy Hence my asking Richard for a little more meat on this bone ... as written it's not scoped well enough to fit.

Answer (score 2):

[Inshallah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inshallah) is simply the Arabic for 'God willing' or 'if God wills'. If any person of any religion were to say "God willing" in Arabic, they would say "Inshallah". The word '[Allah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allah)' just means 'God' in Arabic, and is used by Arabic Christians to refer to the Christian God. 'Inshallah' is used by Christians to express the concept of "If God wills" (which is found in [James 4: 13-15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=james%204%3A%2013-15&version=NIV), and is not spoken by Jesus). Although widely associated with Islam, it is not specifically an Islamic expression.

So the concept of things happening only 'if God wills' exist both in Christianity and Islam, and the same word is used for both in Arabic, which is 'Inshallah'. Deducing from that support by the New Testament writers for Islam (which post-dated the New Testament by hundreds of years) would be unwarranted.

Comment: The Spanish language has a word _ojalá_ which is derived from this Arabic expression, and is used not uncommonly by Christians. In fact, Spanish Biblical translations do use this word to translate words like ὄφελον,  לוּא and אַחֲלַי .